# docker container exec mikro-orm migration wont exit after success

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, mikro-orm

I have an ecs container that im running for my mikro-orm migrations. I need this container to exit after success for the task to stop running.

I have tried numerous different approaches such as:

```
"command": [
            "/bin/bash",
            "-c",
            "npx mikro-orm migration:up && echo 'pass' || echo 'fail'"
        ],
```

and

```
"command": [
            "/bin/bash",
            "-c",
            "npx mikro-orm migration:up; exit $?"
        ],
```

However none of these work. I always stay on "**[32mSuccessfully migrated up to the latest version[39m**"

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can force the container to exit once completed successfully?

Comment: Containers usually exit once their foreground process exits. I would assume the problem in your case is that "/bin/bash" as a shell does not exit after executing your command. Is there any reason you are not specifying the command directly, without bash?

Comment: It gives the same issue doing it directly. I moved to doing it in bash because it wasn't exiting after executing.

Comment: Also I should note, it’s the same behaviour when you do the migrations directly the command line.

Comment: Then my next best guess (since your 'pass' or 'fail' is never printed to the console) is that your `npx mikro-orm migration:up` command does not complete for some reason. Maybe you could look for that specific issue? In that case it would not be docker-related after all.